# how to get process descriptor given a pid in user space Linux

Tags: linux, process

how to get process descriptor given a pid in user space Linux.
We are doing a porting project from OS900 to Linux, converting all system calls.
I tried using find_task_by_pid() in a test code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <include/linux/sched.h>
//#include <Linux/include/linux/pid.h>
    //find_task_by_pid(getpid());
    pid_task(find_vpid(getpid()), PIDTYPE_PID);

    but it is not compiling
    error: ‘PIDTYPE_PID’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: Which header file did you included? pid.h?

Comment: #include <include/linux/sched.h>
#include <Linux/include/linux/pid.h>